How can I define an emit which doesn't have any args in Vue 3.3+ ? (TypeScript)
From Vue 3.3 is possible to define emits in TypeScript like this
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits<{
  change: [id: number]
  update: [value: string]
}>()
</script>

How can I define an emit which doesn't require any args?

Use an empty array as a type:  change: []

To define a emit that doesn't require any args in Vue 3.3+ with Typescript, you can simply omit the argument type:
 <script setup lang="ts">
   const emit = defineEmits<{
     change: []
     update: []
   }>()
 </script>

